# knn imputation of categorical variables in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, imputation

I am trying to implement kNN from the fancyimpute module on a dataset. I was able to implement the code for continuous variables of the datasets using the code below:

```
knn_impute2=KNN(k=3).complete(train[['LotArea','LotFrontage']])
```

It yields the desirable answer as follows: [This show how the original dataset looks like and how it has changed using knn imputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFjKH.png)

I tried to implement the same code for categorical datasets and I get error :

```
could not convert string to float: 'female'
```

Here is the code I used(I am trying to use Imputer):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent', axis=0)
imp.fit(df['sex'])
print(imp.transform(df['sex']))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Recap, I want to use knn imputation on this dataset to impute the sex columns. Below is the dataset.

[The dataset i want to impute using knn imputation with k value 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctftn.png)

How can i do that with knnimpute or i need to write my own functions. If yes, can anyone help me. Thnks

Comment: Most scikit-learn estimators / transformers only deal in numbers, not strings. So first convert your string categorical data to numerical and then try

Comment: Sure. I am already thinking of an idea. But Imputer can not convert np.NaN into labels

Comment: How do you define distances, Euclidean or otherwise, between categories / categorical variables?

Comment: I used the euclidean distance, otherwise, it is stated to use hamming distance for categorical variables

Comment: what's the definition of Euclidean distance between two objects that are not defined on a Euclidean coordinate system? EG. I can easily one-hot-encode "category1", "category2", and "category3". But I can't determine their relative distances.

Comment: @Alex. Basically, what you are saying makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to impute the categorical variables using the steps listed below. I will gladly welcome any omissions or program that can perform such tasks automatically

Step1: Subsets the object's data types(all) into another container

Step2: Change `np.NaN` into an object data type, say `None`. Now, the container is made up of only `objects` data types

Step3: Change the entire container into categorical datasets

Step4: Encode the data set(i am using .cat.codes)

Step5: Change back the value of encoded `None` into `np.NaN`

Step5: Use KNN (from fancyimpute) to impute the missing values

Step6: Re-map the encoded dataset to its initial names

Comment: R package [imputeMulti](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeMulti/index.html)... I don't work in Python, so can't provide a reference

Answer (score -1):

`Imputer` works only on numbers. You can convert the 'sex' column to numbers 1 and 0 using the map function

```
df.sex=df.sex.map({'female':1,'male':0})
```

After this you can use `Imputer` to fill all missing values with 1 or 0 and use the map function again to convert 'sex' back to string values (if you need to).

Comment: I did that already. Remember that there is np.NaN in the sex columns and Imputer can not convert that to a label.

Comment: @KINNI No, Imputer can handle np.nan as given in this example - scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/…. It will return an integer, which you can convert back to label

Comment: I will retry that and post the error i get. I will appreciate you try it and post the output you get.

Comment: how did you handle your problem , i have the same

Comment: This trick works on binary category only where the "mean" of 0s and 1s can be reinterpreted back into 0 or 1 using rounding (0.7 is roughly female, 0.2 is roughly male, using your example.) In situations where there is more than 2 categories, don't use this trick. Frame challenge: you have categories mapped {dog: 1, cat: 2, bird: 3}. Imputer gives you 2. Are you sure the Imputer is not trying to average out dog and bird as its prediction?